# SQL Server - view all foreign key dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find all of the db objects which are dependent on a given table, including other tables which reference the given table through foreign keys.  I tried using "sp_depends" and it gives me the sprocs, views, and triggers but doesn't tell me what other tables have foreign keys to the given table.  Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)
    from sys.foreign_keys
    where referenced_object_id = object_id('SchemaName.TableName')
```

Answer (score 2):

The key ingredient is the sys.foreign_keys view. I found a query that might be useful as an example in an article at mssqltips.com... [Identify all of your foreign keys in a SQL Server database](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1151)

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS: right click your table and click `"View Dependencies"`

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I want to be able to do it in SQL - I will most likely be generating a report of dependencies

Comment: it only show dependencies of stored procedures, triggers and other stuff .. not foreign key dependency

Answer (score 1):

Also try this  :

```
USE AUX; <- use your database name
GO
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey,
SCHEMA_NAME(f.SCHEMA_ID) SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID) ReferenceSchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
GO
```

and before the last GO you can add `where OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) = 'your_table_name'` to see only dependency for that table.

It will print `TableName | Column name (FK) | Reference TableName | Reference Column Name`

Comment: This is the best answer, I think.